# Objeto se detiene bruscamente (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity, vr

Estoy haciendo un pequeño juego para aprender a usar Unity, y surgió un problema:

Tengo una esfera que se mueve automáticamente a tres puntos (target, target(1) y target(2)) cíclicamente. Hasta ahora se movía sin ningún problema, hasta que incluí una función de que emita un sonido cuando ocurre una colisión.

La pelota se mueve tranquilamente hasta el primer punto, emite el sonido, se dirige al segundo y se queda quieta, no se mueve. Ni siquiera cuando existe una colisión con el jugador emite el sonido.

¿Alguien sabe por qué pasa esto?

¿Error de código?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Función de sonido:**

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class play_campana : MonoBehaviour
{

    public AudioSource Campana;

    void Start(){
        Campana = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
    }


    void Update()
    {

    }
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
     //if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
     //   {
            Campana.Play();
      //  }
    }
}
```

**Función de mover:**

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class move : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform[] target;
    public float speed;

    private int current;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (transform.position != target[current].position)
        {
            Vector3 pos = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target[current].position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MovePosition(pos);

        }
        else
        {
            current = (current + 1) % target.Length;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Si existe un error en la consola de Untiy, inclúyelo por favor. Así tendremos más información sobre qué está pasando. Si has encontrado la problema, actualiza el post mostrando la solución.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo tal vez sea un error arrojado por que no le haz asignado el audio source a el script play_campana. intenta agregarle el audio source que no encuentra arrastrando el mismo objeto en el campo.